# efficiency boost::thread group

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-thread, point-clouds

I want to improve the efficiency of my program, in this purpose i try to parallelize the tasks which can be. I'm working with point cloud, so we are talking about big data, 17000 points approximately.

This is the code before:

```
void Estimator::extract_relevant_points(std::vector<Point3D>& relevant_points, std::vector<Point3D>& pointcloud, doubleIE cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, doubleIE cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)
    {
    for(int i = 0; i < pointcloud.size(); i++) {
       //Doing my operations ...
    }
}
```

The code now is :

```
void Estimator::extract_relevant_points_multithread(std::vector<Point3D>& relevant_points, std::vector<Point3D>& pointcloud, doubleIE cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, doubleIE cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)
    {
        std::cout << "pointcloud = " << pointcloud.size ()<< std::endl;

        boost::thread_group group;

        for(int i = 0; i < pointcloud.size(); i++) {
            group.create_thread(boost::bind(&IntervalMapEstimator::extract_relevant_point_in_thread, i,boost::ref(relevant_points), boost::ref(pointcloud), boost::cref(cell_min_angle_sensor_rot), boost::cref(cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)));
        }
        std::cout << "size group before join = " << group.size ()<< std::endl;
        group.join_all();
        std::cout << "size group after join = " << group.size ()<< std::endl;
    }

void Estimator::extract_relevant_point_in_thread(int i, std::vector<Point3D>& relevant_points, std::vector<Point3D>& pointcloud, doubleIE cell_min_angle_sensor_rot, doubleIE cell_max_angle_sensor_rot)
    {
        //Doing my operations
    }
```

But the new code is crashing on the run, i can't understand why. Does any body have an idea ?
Also i putted little chrono to get the time spent on this function and it seems like the new version is taking more time than the first... can't understand why either ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code creates a thread for each of 17000 points. That is bound to crash your application because each thread requires minimum 2MB stack totalling to 34GB of stack, unless you have more RAM than that.

Use [gcc parallel algorithms](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_using.html) or [Intel TBB parallel algorithms](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-generic-parallel-algorithms) or [Intel TBB task scheduler](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-task-based-programming).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

I think i will be able to resolve the problem with a threadpool pattern, do you think that would work ? 
But how many thread should run simultaneously too be the more efficient ?
My CPU has 8 cores, so I'm gonna guess on that.

TBB looks interesting, but i would prefer to do it my self.

Comment: In the end, i will try to use the TBB library. This way the code is optimized for each machine.